# Redirecting the output of a child process

Tags: c, shell, unix, io-redirection

There are several ways of redirecting the output of a child process:

1. using `freopen(3)`
2. using `dup(3)`
3. using `popen(3)`
4. ...

What should one pick if all is wanted is to execute a child process and have it output saved in a given file, pretty much like the `ls > files.txt` works?

What is normally used by shells?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can discover what your favorite shell uses by `strace(1)`ing your shell.

In one terminal:

```
echo $$
```

In another terminal:

```
strace -o /tmp/shell -f -p [PID from the first shell]
```

In the first terminal again:

```
ls > files.txt
```

In the second terminal, `^C` your `strace(1)` command and then edit the `/tmp/shell` output file to see what system calls it made to do the redirection.

---

`freopen(3)` manipulates the C standard IO `FILE*` pointers. All this will be thrown away on the other side of the `execve(2)` call, because it is maintained in *user memory*. You could use this *after* the `execve(2)` call, but that would be awkward to use generically.

`popen(3)` opens a single unidirectional `pipe(7)`. This is useful, but extremely limited -- you get either the standard output descriptor *or* the standard input descriptor. This would fail for something like `ls | grep foo | sort` where both input and output must be redirected. So this is a poor choice.

`dup2(2)` will manage file descriptors -- a kernel-implemented resource -- so it will persist across `execve(2)` calls *and* you can set up as many file descriptors as you need, which is nice for `ls > /tmp/output 2> /tmp/error` or handling both input *and* output: `ls | sort | uniq`.

There is another mechanism: `pty(7)` handling. The `forkpty(3)`, `openpty(3)`, functions can manage a new pseudo-terminal device created specifically to handle another program. The [Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment, 2nd edition book](http://www.apuebook.com/) has a very nice `pty` example program in its source code, though if you're having trouble understanding why this would be useful, take a look at the `script(1)` program -- it creates a new pseudo-terminal and uses it to record all input and output to and from programs and stores the transcript to a file for later playback or documentation. You can also use it to script actions in interactive programs, similar to `expect(1)`.

Answer (score 2):

I would expect to find `dup2()` used mainly.

Neither `popen()` nor `freopen()` is designed to handle redirections such as `3>&7`.  Up to a point, `dup()` could be used, but the `3>&7` example shows where `dup()` starts to creak; you'd have to ensure that file descriptors 4, 5, and 6 are open (and 7 is not) before it would handle what `dup2()` would do without fuss.

Comment: I've just examined strace output, following the suggestion of @sarnold, bash uses `dup2()`. So you seems to be right! +1