# How to accept file argument in C?

Tags: c, bash

I know, if ran in bash, my program is supposed to able to handle arguments like (where a.out is the name of file):

$ a.out <inputFile

Does this mean that inputFile is argv[1]? If so, what is the data type of argv[1] in case I need to pass it in to some other function? Would I read it using something like:
FILE *fopen( const char * filename, const char * mode );

OR

Does that mean I have to accept input from user getchar() or something?

How do I deal with such situations?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12812579/how-redirection-internally-works-in-unix) may be helpful

Answer (score 2):

There's two ways to receive input:

- Via STDIN, which is a pre-defined filehandle (fd `0` or `STDIN_FILENO`) you can read from at any time.
- Via command-line arguments passed by `argv`

The shell interprets redirection operators to adjust what STDIN actually is, so by the time the program runs the only arguments left are:

```
"a.out"
```

The redirection is gone. It's just "piped" into STDIN.

> Shell operators like `<`, `>` and `|` are interpreted by the shell before your program is run. The same goes for interpolation like `$` variables and other shell-specific functions.

Answer (score 2):

The command

```
./a.out < inputFile
```

isn't passing arguments to the program, instead if does ***redirection***.

That means the shell will set up standard input (`stdin`, which e.g. `scanf` reads from) in your program to read from the redirected file.

To pass an actual argument to the program you need to run it as:

```
./a.out inputFile
```

In this case `argc` will be equal to `2`, and `argv[1]` will be the *string* `"inputFile"`. Which you can then pass on to e.g. `fopen`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a path to the c program then use `fopen()`

Answer (score 0):

Using "<" means you are redirecting standard input of your process to be read from inputFile. So, all the standard read routines (getchar(), cin << ...) can be used.

If you omit "<", then inputFile becomes command argument and it is passed as part of `char* argv[]` to your main. After checking argc, validating file exists etc., you can use file reading routines, like `fopen`.